# React native android transitions are really slow

Tags: android, performance, react-native

My react native transitions (using the Navigator) are really slow, dropping the javascript thread frames to 0 for a second or two when the animation first starts, then picking up to ~20, then pausing halfway through, and then usually finishing relatively smoothly. I'm testing on a clean Galaxy Note 4, so it's not an emulator issue.

I'm rendering empty views with InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions and then a 5-element listview after the animation is complete. I've compiled the app for production and turned dev mode off.

Is this expected/the current state of things (hopefully to improve), or am I probably doing something wrong? If so, what's the best way to hunt that down? I have very little logic running.

If there isn't an easy solution, is there a way to disable animations on Navigator transitions?

Answer (score 36):

Turn off chrome debugger, it makes animation really slow.

Comment: Do they have any explanation for this though? It's difficult to debug when theres slight inconsistencies with the iOS version.

Comment: You welcome :) @NaotoIda, I guess that it's extending the debug cycles, by the data transmission and by the necessary operations to debug.

Comment: This was very useful!

Comment: Thanks. This was helpful.

Answer (score 15):

in the ios simulator, command+T slows animations down. Android probably has something similar

Comment: Life saver! (I came here looking for slow animations in the iOS simulator :-) )

Comment: I was looking for this for ios. But it's not command+T on the xcode, it's on the simulator. Thanks!

Comment: thanks @josualeonard, I've edited my response to reflect your correction.

Comment: Thanks so much! I've wasted so much time trying to figure out what's wrong with the debugger...

Answer (score 4):

The official docs have [a page on Performance](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html), you might want to check that. It has a section talking specifically about [slow Navigator transitions](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#slow-navigator-transitions).

Also, I've noticed that React Native v0.14.0 with Chrome debugger enabled is really slow, try disabling it first.

Navigator transitions are in the [`NavigatorSceneConfigs` module](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js), but it doesn't seem to have an animationless transition.